# Can I use the context param of lambda function for this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, amazon-dynamodb

I have 2 react native apps that are connected to a single aws backend. And I have deployed a post-confirmation lambda function so that I can save items (Users etc.) into the dynamo db storage. I want to know how do I adjust my lambda function so that If someone signup from the user side of my app it save an item in the user table of dynamo db and if someone signup from the driver side of the app it saves an item in the driver table of dynamo db. Can I use context param to check whether from which side of the app someone is signing up?

Comment: Wouldn't these be two different API calls?

Comment: Thanks, @jarmod actually I'm very new to this, what I know is when someone signup from both of these apps the same lambda function run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clientMetaData` to pass parameters to the `PostConfirmation` Lambda function.

```
await Auth.signUp({
  username, 
  password,
  clientMetadata: {
    isDriver: false,
  },
});
```

and in the `PostConfirmation` Lambda

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  AWS.config.region = event.region;

  // you can access like this 
  // event.request.clientMetadata.isDriver 

  context.succeed(event);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, @LuckyTuvshee I think this will work I will check.